# Find the Standard Form for this plane containing these three points

Tags: linear-algebra

A plane contains three points, (-1, 2, 3), (0, 1, -1), (1, 0, 2).
Find the Standard Form for this plane.

This exercise was in my textbook, and the answer at the back is:
-7x-5y=-3

My answer is: 
-7x-7y=-7

I have a feeling that the the answer provided by the book is wrong (wouldn't be the first time).

---

Here's how I got my answer:

Standard Form:
ax+by+cz=d

n=(a, b, c), so I first find vector n.
n=(q-p)X(r-p)

So I assigned the three points to p, q, and r
P(-1, 2, 3)
Q(0, 1, -1)
R(1, 0, 2)

Then,
n=(1, -1, -4)X(2, -2, -1)
 =((1-8), -(-1--8), (-2--2))
 =(-7, -7, 0) Wolframalpha gave me this exact same answer

Finally, to find d for the Standard Form,
d=n.p
 =(-7, -7, 0).(-1, 2, 3)
 =(7-14)
 =-7

Then putting all these together, the Standard Form I got is:
-7x-7y=-7

Comment: Yours must be correct as the 3 points are on it.

Comment: Yep, solved it as well. Your solution looks to be correct.

Comment: Much appreciated guys, god damn it I hate this book. I'm not sure why my professor instructed us to purchase it. "Elementary Linear Algebra by stewart venit".